# When an error occurs try catch stops an Express server from crashing. However, If the route doesn't stop how do I send the client an error page?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

**Question:** When an error occurs `try catch` stops an Express server from crashing.  However, If the route doesn't stop how do I send the client an error page?

**Background:** Maybe I'm approaching this wrong but shouldn't the client receive an error page if there is a database error or similar problem?

**Example**: In the simplified example below `try catch` keeps the server from crashing. However, it also stops `500.html` from being sent to the client because the event loop always reaches `res.render('homepage')` and sends that.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    let cat = 10;

    try {
        if (cat === 10) throw new Error('cat should not be 10');
    } catch(error) {
        next(error);
    }

    res.render('homepage');
}

// custom error handler
app.use( function(error, req, res, next) {

    console.log(error);
    let filePath = path.join(__dirname, '/error-pages/500.html');
    res.status(500).sendFile(filePath);

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I think you maybe are missing is that the `next()` function doesn't stop your application from going to the next instruction which is `res.render('homepage');`.
I believe that `res.render('homepage');` runs before your handler has to oportunity to.
You could either place `res.render('homepage');` inside the try block

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    let cat = 10;

    try {
        if (cat === 10) throw new Error('cat should not be 10');
        res.render('homepage');
    } catch(error) {
        next(error);
    }
}
```

or return inside the catch block. It will depend on what you wish from your logic.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    let cat = 10;

    try {
        if (cat === 10) throw new Error('cat should not be 10');
    } catch(error) {
        return next(error);
    }
    res.render('homepage');
}
```

Comment: `return` is such a brilliant and simple solution.